# Firefox CSS3 parallax: Z translated content disappears

Tags: css, firefox, parallax

I have been facing a very irritating error with firefox over the last day.

I have replicated the bug here: http://jsfiddle.net/kmz9tv77/1/

There is one `container` div, with two children, `bgpanel` a red background div with the text background, and `fgpanel` a purple background div with the text foreground, and an opacity of 0.5.

The container div has a `perspective` value of 1px, the `bgpanel` is `translateZ(-1px)` and then scaled by 2, to keep the perceived size the same.
The fgpanel is as it is.

The idea is to generate a parallax effect while scrolling. The `bgpanel` div will move slower, while `fgpanel` will move at the same speed.

On chrome this works perfectly. On Safari too. On firefox, halfway down the scroll the layer farther away, `bgpanel`, suddenly decides to vanish. If I force firefox to repaint by going to the element inspector and switching the `top` property on and off on bgpanel, things work again for a while, but again `bgpanel` goes off if you scroll down beyond a point.

What's happening?! Am I missing something fundamental here? Help!

Comment: a perspective of 1 px is way too low. This property is not intended to work at such a low value. You should try to reproduce you effect with a huigher perspective value

Comment: @vals: I had thought so as well, but the same issue comes up even at a perspective of a 1000px. http://jsfiddle.net/kmz9tv77/2/

Comment: I am having the same issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146084/css-parallax-working-beautifully-in-chrome-but-not-firefox#