# CSS Parallax working beautifully in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, parallax

The website is temporarily hosted [here](http://torjinx.me/nic-whitehouse).

I used the Pure CSS Parallax example [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/).

All the HTML, CSS and JavaScript should be viewable under View Page Source. The parallax effect works beautifully in Chrome. In Firefox, the effect works but background images start to disappear when I scroll past a certain point!

Comment: For me work fine in FF 46, and not Chrome 50  and OPERA 37

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout http://caniuse.com/ it shows you what every browser supports or not. Every browsers is different as you know, there might be elements on Edge and FF that might not be supported like they are on Chrome.

Comment: The issue appears to be with translateZ in Firefox (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927646/firefox-ie-parallax-divs-disappear-when-scrolled), but http://caniuse.com/ doesn't mention anything about it.