# Firefox, IE- parallax divs disappear when scrolled

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to web design and I've been working on a pure CSS layered parallax page, like a landscape effect with overlapping div containers stacked at different depths... and to my pleasure I got it working perfectly in Chrome.

However when I load it in Firefox (ver. 47) (using Windows 10) it looks fine until I scroll down. My divs and their content completely disappear after various points and reappear when I scroll back up. Alternatively I can resize the browser and everything reloads perfectly, but will disappear again if I continue scrolling.

In IE and Edge the content disappears after completely scrolling off the top and doesn't appear when I scroll back up. Only reappears after resizing.

I have tried adding the browser specific prefixes and what not and that didn't help at all. I also tried changing the perspective value as noted in a similar post but that didn't fix it either. What is causing this discrepancy between the presentation in chrome and the others?

Here is my code, I have replaced the div background images with colors.
Thanks
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <link href="../CSS/Styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="bannerlogo" src="http://placehold.it/350x65">
        <div id="back1">
            <p id="text1">Splash Text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="back2">
            <p id="text2">Splash Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="back3"></div>
        <div id="back4"></div>  
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

body { 
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: url(../IMAGES/Layer1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

#text1, #text2{
    position:relative;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:courier new;
}
#bannerlogo{
    width:75%;
    max-width:700px;
}
#text1{
    left:-10%;
    top:60%;
    font-size:4vw;
}
#text2{
    left:-5%;
    top:60%;
    font-size:4vw;
}
#content{
    position:relative;
    height:700px;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:rgb(3,0,20);
    z-index:10;
}

#footer{
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    width:100vw;
    background-color:rgb(30,30,50);
    z-index:15;
}

#back1, #back2, #back3, #back4{

    position:relative;
    right:0px;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    min-width:1280px;
    min-height:720px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size: 200%;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    line-height:100%;
    transform-style:inherit;
    min-height:100vh;
}

#back1{
    background-color:rgb(100,100,150);
    transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(6) translateY(0%);
    z-index:-1;
    margin-bottom:-30vh;

}
#back2{
    background-color:rgba(100,150,100,.7);
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3.5);
}
#back3{
    background-color:rgba(150,100,100,.5);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2) translateY(-25%);
}
#back4{
    min-height:0px;
    height:30vh;
    background-color:rgb(3,0,20);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2) translateY(20%);
    margin-bottom:-30vh;
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you can add either a jsfiddle or snippet, to assist people in reviewing / resolving your issue.

Comment: K, I haven't used either before, hope this works https://jsfiddle.net/8jry9uqk/

Comment: Perfect! I can see exactly what you're talking about now on FF. I'll see what I can troubleshoot.

Comment: As far as I can see it is related to the html overflow:hidden, however if I change that it breaks the parallax effect.

Comment: hmm.. the issue only occurs with translateZ being set. When I set them all to 0 they don't disappear when scrolling. There must be some issue with firefox's interpretation of the translate... yet when you resize the window it corrects everything...

Comment: I'm having the same issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146084/css-parallax-working-beautifully-in-chrome-but-not-firefox#